# How to print item position of rendered element Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, arraylist

So, I have a list of items. I like to print only in the list who has a length of more than 0.

```js
  lists = [
    {
      item: 1,
      length: 4,
    },
    {
      item: 2,
      length: 0,
    },
    {
      item: 3,
      length: 3,
    },
    {
      item: 4,
      length: 0,
    },
    {
      item: 5,
      length: 3,
    },
  ];
```

Currently, It is showing the array index of list!

```js
<ul *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index">
  <li *ngIf="list.length">{{ list.item }} INDEX #{{ i }}</li>
</ul>
```

Current output:

- 1 INDEX #**0**
- 3 INDEX #**2**
- 5 INDEX #**4**

But I am looking for a solution so that the expected result should be like

- 1 INDEX #**0**
- 3 INDEX #**1**
- 5 INDEX #**2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter `lists` and then run it with `ngFor`:

```js
get filteredList(): TheTypeOfTheList[] {
  return this.lists.filter(l => l.length);
}
```

```html
<ul *ngFor="let list of filteredList; let i = index">
  <li *ngIf="list.length">{{ list.item }} INDEX #{{ i }}</li>
</ul>
```

Output would be

```
// 1 INDEX #0
// 3 INDEX #1
// 5 INDEX #2
```